# gem install does not install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this version of ruby:

ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x64-mingw32]

How do I solve this error.

ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        The last version of nokogiri (>= 1.6) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.10.9. Try installing it with `gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.9` and then running the current command again
        nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.3, < 2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.0.0.

Comment: How did you install ruby?  Did you install the devkit?  There are notes on the nokogiri website about installing it on windows: https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#windows. It's a long time since I tried to install rails on windows, it's always easier on Linux or Mac.  Try using a Linux VM for rails dev.  It will save you lots of time in the long run.

Comment: Have you tried what it recommended? Try installing just Nokogiri and give the results. run `gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.9` and if you get errors add them to your question.

Comment: I install an older version then things started working.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (04-02-2020) Ruby 2.7.0 on Windows is only supported in the latest release candidate of nokogiri, see [their git repo](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/releases/tag/v1.11.0.rc2).

You can (install pre-releases)[https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#prerelease-gems] with the `--pre` flag of `gem`:
`gem install nokogiri --pre`